# How to create custom column into azure applicationInsights

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-function-app-proxy

My application is Microsoft Azure Function App.
Using with HttpTrigger along with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging - ILogger.

How to add custom column into Application Insights - Request, trace table.

That column to co-relate the application reference ID with application insight's operation id.

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how to use your own `TelemetryClient` which can run in parallel to `ILogger` and give you the full flexibility to put telemetry into AppInsights: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/App-Insights#custom-telemetry

Also you can take a look at this to add custom dimensions using `ILogger`directly: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/ILogger#structured-logging

Comment: Ok, here, How to add structure Logging (custom proerty through customDimension) for "request"